# How can I use an Ecto query to request the timezone from the database?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Beyond the obvious

```
SQL.query!(Repo, """SHOW TIMEZONE""", [])
```

Is there anyway to use an Ecto query to request the server timezone?

Comment: `grep TIMEZONE` doesn't return anything in the ecto and postgrex repositories so I'm pretty sure there isn't a wrapper for that.

Comment: Dogbert - I had a feeling that might be the case, but I couldn't find confirmation one way or the other anywhere.